# How to store set of tuples into cassandra using datastax driver

Tags: cassandra, micronaut, datastax-java-driver

I'm trying to run my service with Micronaut and Cassandra (currently version `3.11.10`) and store a column that is a set of tuples into Cassandra.

example code:

```
QueryBuilder
    .insertInto(table)
    .value("column", QueryBuilder.literal(items.map { it.toTuple() }.toSet())))
```

The `toTuple()` method is just an extension method that transfer the items into `Term` objects

When I'm doing so I'm receiving the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: Could not inline literal of type java.util.Collections$SingletonSet. This happens because the driver doesn't know how to map it to a CQL type. Try passing a TypeCodec or CodecRegistry to literal().
```

I've checked online in multiple sources but couldn't find a simple way to store a set of tuples into the database without implementing my custom `TypeCodec`. As I'm sure that I'm not the first person to have this issue, I'm probably doing something completely wrong, however I couldn't find any documentation regarding to what is the correct way of doing this.